# How to Get PyInstaller To Find Missing Imports?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

When building with PyInstaller I'm getting this error...

```
ImportError: No module named <module name>
```

The modules in question are contained in sub-folders within the project folder.

Functions within those modules are imported like so...

```
from data.cache_handler import replace_cache_key_value
```

PyInstaller doesn't find 'cache_handler'.

How can I make it find it?

I've tried...

Adding `--hidden-import cache_handler` to the build command.

I've tried editing the spec file, adding...

```
hiddenimports=['cache_handler']
```

Still no luck.